# App keeps crashing after moving to new page

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have the following code in android studio. I would like to move to a new page in android but the app keeps crashing, any idea?

```
lst1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.courseregapp.View.class);
           
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you paste the error also?

Comment: and getApplicationContext() should not be used in intents, You can use ClassName.this or  getActivity()

Comment: I replaced getApplicationContext() with SecondActivity.this but the error is again Application has stopped, application keeps stopping

Comment: @Rahul Sharma Can you help with new question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is crashing because you are providing application context to intent instead of providing class context. Your code should be like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentClassName.this, View.class);
       
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you it works! I have another question can you help?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73746675/sqlite-record-not-inserted